# membership provider with hardcoded users and roles

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-membership

I have fully working custom membership provider with implemented many features. Now this is ok for serious applications, but I'm wonder how can I implement membership provider, with hardcoded usernames and corresponding roles, for example

- userOne = Admin access
- userTwo = Limited access
- userThree = read only

I do not need any crud operations, maybe edit password later, but now it's not important, cause I want to find a way around fully membership provider, in this situation it's overengineered solution.

Any links, ideas, code examples are welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that?

Anyway, you `Dictionary` to do so.

Here's an example.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("userOne", "Admin access");

string access = string.Empty;
dic.TryGetValue("userOne", out access);
```

You can call `dic.Add()` as many times as you want. You can even pull data from text file using `FileSystem` or from Database.
You can also pass a variable with `TryGetValue`.

```
string username = txtUserName.Text;
dic.TryGetValue(username, out access);
```